# How do I completely remove LXD from my system?

Tags: snap, lxd

I am running version 22.04.01 of Ubuntu and I installed LDX using the apt with the lxd-installer package.

How do I completely remove LXD from my system?

Answer (score 8):

LXD is installed as a snap. To remove it, run:

```
sudo snap remove --purge lxd
```

Afterwards, you can remove the `lxd-installer` helper package:

```
sudo apt remove --purge lxd-installer
```

The `--purge` option in both commands ensures complete removal of everything, including configuration files etc.

Comment: I'd add `--purge` to the `snap remove` to "completely" remove it.